# How to install/use GtkWebkit/webview in my gtk+ program using C with Windows XP as OS

Tags: c, windows, webkit, webview, gtk

I am hardly trying to use the GtkWebKit (webview widget) of gtk+ using C. The operating system of my choice is Windows XP. I successfully managed to install gtk+ on my Windows XP system (using MS Visual Studio 2010, no cygwin or mingwm is installed!). What do I have to install to use the GtkWebKit in my program under Windows XP? Unfortunately I did not found any tutorial, link after an intensive Google search.

Hints, Links, ... are highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance,
Jonas